# Target specific values while looping through rows in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, reference, copy, copy-paste

Second Question
Hello all,
Here I go with my Second Query;

I am trying to write a vba code, through looping, which could do the following in the sheet http://speedy.sh/pvVEX/stack1.xlsx

1) Check sheet BE for how many apples does `Aasif` have and plug it in `Sheet1`, where row is `Aasif` and column is `Apples`, then check how many `oranges` does `Aasif` have and plug in where row is `Aasif` and column is `Oranges`

2) After checking for all fruits, it should come to next person, `Aeleta` and then again the same for each column

I am new to vba looping, though I have made a few other queries, so help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not include the data structure or table in the question either as `code` or a graphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard ;)
Please see [a good starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317029/need-help-making-the-vba-excel-code-better/16317480#16317480)

I am giving you code that works with the spreadsheet you have provided in link. It will populate `"Sheet1"` based on the list in `"Sheet2"`
**note:** *make sure your sheets are called Sheet1 and Sheet2 or modify the code accordingly*

```
Sub Main()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet ' sheet variables declaration
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1"): Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2") ' binding sheets to variables

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range ' range variables
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long ' iterators

' for each cell in column F in sheet2
For i = 2 To ws2.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("F" & i) ' binding cells from column F (sheet2) to rng2 variable
    ' for each cell in column B on sheet1
    For j = 2 To ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = ws1.Range("B" & j) ' binding cells from column B (sheet1) to rng1 variable
        ' comparing both words ( names )
        If StrComp(rng2, rng1, 1) = 0 Then
            For Each Column In Sheet1
            For k = 3 To ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                ' if the name of column matches the offset or rng2 (name)
                If StrComp(rng2.Offset(0, 1), Cells(1, k), 1) = 0 Then
                    ' copy/paste the amount of fruits from sheet2 to corresponding cells in sheet1
                    Cells(rng1.Row, k) = rng2.Offset(0, 2)
                End If
            Next k ' next column
        End If
        Set rng1 = Nothing
    Next j ' next row in sheet1
    Set rng2 = Nothing
Next i ' next row in sheet2
```

End Sub

The results
[image: Results]

Comment: hi mehow, thanks alot for the help, can you please explain, if you don't mind that which code is doing what here?

Comment: @MyNameIsSlimChady yes, I have added comments in the code, see updated answer

Comment: this code is working, but if I extend the table either on Sheet1 or Sheet2 it does not respond. Would it be possible to continue till isempty condition is met on sheet2? 

I am actually pulling data through SQL, and putting it in a more graphical format, hence the number of entries vary.

Comment: that's what it exactly does. it picks up the last cell used in the list. this code solves your problem you can accept the answer (green check mark) thats how we say thank you here on stackoverflow. if you want to get more help, I am afraid you will have to ask a new question. thanks

Comment: oh yes, got it dude, sorry my bad, still trying to get my head around the loops thing :s, should i say without much success :(

Comment: @MyNameIsSlimChady just start another question, explain your problem and Im sure somebody will help you solve your problem and/or understand loops